# Stringify array-like object with mixed index types

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object which is sort of like an array, but it has a mix of index types (numbers and strings). For example:

```
var myObj = [];
myObj[0] = 'a';
myObj[1] = 'b';
myObj[2] = 'c';
myObj['x'] = 'y';
```

When I stringify it using `JSON.stringify()` and then parse it again using `JSON.parse()` the `myObj['x'] = 'y';` bit is lost. How can I overcome this?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using an array like this. Why do you have this weird mix of index types? (And what happens if you want to use `5` and `'5'` as indexes separately?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a mix of keys, it’s no longer an array. Use an object.

```
var myObj = {};
myObj[0] = 'a';
myObj[1] = 'b';
myObj[2] = 'c';
myObj.x = 'y';
```

If you need to calculate length or perform other array-like options, that’ll have to be managed manually.

There is always overriding `toJSON`, but I’d avoid that:

```
myObj.toJSON = function() {
    var r = {};

    for (var k in this)
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(k))
            r[k] = this[k];

    return r;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is not a true array but rather a sort of hash map which JavaScript objects are more suitable for, so change the following line:

```
var myObj = [];
```

To this:

```
var myObj = {};
```